# Bootstrap icons not showing up when using PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I'm reading values from MySQL using PHP but my bootstrap icons aren't showing up.

Here's a part of my code, could someone telling me what I'm doing wrong?

```
switch($val)
        {
            case(1):
                $icon="icon-check icon-green";
                break;
            case(2):
                $icon="icon-plus-sign icon-blue";
                break;
            case(3):
                $icon="icon-check icon-yellow";
                break;
            case(4):
                $icon="icon-remove-circle icon-red";
                break;
        }

        echo '<pre style="background:#F2F2F2;"><i class="' . $icon . '"></i><code style="color:#4169E1;">' . $val1 .  '</code><strong> ' . $val2 . 'd</strong> text '. $val3 .' <span style="color:#7A8B8B;">@</span> ' . $val4 . '<br><i class="icon-comment icon-blue"></i><em><small>"' . $val5 . '"</small></em></pre>';
```

Comment: Have you used <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> in the Head?

Comment: add default case at your switch .. at the moment if value is not 1-4 $icon may not be set at all ..

Comment: try after replacing coma like  <i class='" . $icon . "'>

Comment: @Manish i tried that but i didn't help.

Comment: @Svetlio on my PHP page I can see that the icon is showing up when I check using the console but the actual icon's image isn't showing up.

Comment: @Sameer that didn't help either.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your HTML?

Comment: @Paulie  Is your page online? to check your html..

Comment: @Paulie is the Glyphicons image at correct place? There are 2 images for Glyphicons which must be in public img folder

Comment: @Svetlio how can I do that?

Comment: bootstrap has : css/js/img folder on download. 
the img folder must be at your root folder so those icons to be accesable..

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "icon-blue", "icon-yellow", ... classes.

I think that you can only use icon in white or black color as described here : [Bootstrap icon doc](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons)

Answer (score 0):

a few things - you are not assigning values to $var1, $var2, $var3... you need to do $var=1, $var=2, etc.

Also, turn error reporting on, then you would be getting undefined errors as a clue.
Also, I'd not echo that whole sting - it's really hard to read and maintain, and easy to miss quotes...

instead, consider:

```
<div class ="<?= $foo ?>" >
//more html
</div>
```

it's soooo much easier to read when you have large blocks of html, and less error prone.
finally, don't hard code inline styles, either - keep your CSS, PHP and HTML seperate.

As for the switch, you need to define the switch, but you also need to get at the values, and so you need a loop of some kind for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
<?php
    function myicon($val){
        switch($val)
        {
            case(1):
                return "icon-check icon-green";
                break;
            case(2):
                return "icon-plus-sign icon-blue";
                break;
            case(3):
                return "icon-check icon-yellow";
                break;
            case(4):
                return "icon-flag icon-red";
                break;
        }
    }
?>

<?php for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++):
$icon=myicon($i);
echo $icon;
?>
<div>
<i class="<?= $icon ?>"><?= $icon ?></i>    
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>

OR:

<?php
for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
$icon=myicon($i);
echo "<div>";
echo '<i class="'.$icon.'">'.$icon.'</i>';
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

In this small example, I'd have probably done "if...elseif" rather than switch, but the above code is sure easy for you to re-use now.  Enjoy!
Good luck, I hope that helps - rtm about switch, for...each, while... and the ternary operator, too.